# how to get filename for attached file to reply in IBM Connections 3.0

Tags: atom-feed, ibm-connections

I am working on IBM connections Application. My Application is dependant on IBM connections 3.0 Atom API calls.

While dealing with forums, topics and replies, I found the atom API feed is lacking attached files name.
IBM have separate APIs defined for files which have detailed APIs for "My files" and "Shared Files". But could not find APIs related to Files uploaded in Communities / forums.

Here is portion for atom feed I get while fetching the replies for forum.

```
<snx:field name="Re: New topic test" fid="b4ee2735-aca3-4e57-a2a4-4a027bf1a35a" type="file">
    <link type="image/jpeg" href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/atom/download?nodeId=b4ee2735-aca3-4e57-a2a4-4a027bf1a35a" length="120540"/>
</snx:field>
```

Here is sample of URL I used for getting replies atom feed.

```
http: //myserver.com/forums/atom/replies?topicUuid=_TOPICID_&sortOrder=asc&ps=30
```

**EDIT:**

Here is complete ATOM Feed for the attachment reply

```
<entry>
    <id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:c5db8cbd-5b4e-496c-8480-da2acb60f240</id>
    <title type="text">Re: New topic test</title>
    <published>2014-08-21T06:09:20.887Z</published>
    <updated>2014-08-21T06:17:20.223Z</updated>
    <author><email>vishal.kardode@abc.com</email>
    <name>Vishal Kardode</name>
    <snx:userid>3C557865-5F1B-45CC-8D96-F8836734E8F4</snx:userid>
    <snx:userState>active</snx:userState></author>
    <link href="https://octositc.polarisft.com:9444/forums/atom/reply?replyUuid=c5db8cbd-5b4e-496c-8480-da2acb60f240" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <link href="https://octositc.polarisft.com:9444/forums/atom/reply?replyUuid=c5db8cbd-5b4e-496c-8480-da2acb60f240" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <snx:field name="Re: New topic test" fid="9703a25e-7625-4491-b6d7-d364ac1e9951" type="file">
        <link type="application/json" href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/atom/download?nodeId=9703a25e-7625-4491-b6d7-d364ac1e9951" length="2920"/>
    </snx:field>
    <snx:field name="Re: New topic test" fid="b4ee2735-aca3-4e57-a2a4-4a027bf1a35a" type="file">
        <link type="image/jpeg" href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/atom/download?nodeId=b4ee2735-aca3-4e57-a2a4-4a027bf1a35a" length="120540"/>
    </snx:field>
    <category term="forum-reply" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"/>
    <link href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/html/topic?id=eff2d6c3-e415-4f39-b04e-16bb5e8d9216#c5db8cbd-5b4e-496c-8480-da2acb60f240" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/atom/replies?replyUuid=c5db8cbd-5b4e-496c-8480-da2acb60f240" rel="replies" type="application/atom+xml" thr:count="0"/>
    <thr:in-reply-to ref="urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:eff2d6c3-e415-4f39-b04e-16bb5e8d9216" href="https://lc.myserver.com/forums/atom/topics?forumUuid=eff2d6c3-e415-4f39-b04e-16bb5e8d9216" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <content type="html">
    test attachment
    </content>
    <snx:permissions>none, view_forum, create_post, edit_personal_post, del_personal_post, subscribe, create_topictag, del_personal_topictag, view_category, edit_personal_question</snx:permissions>
</entry>
```

I am using LC 3.0 and it returns topic title in "name" instead of file name for "snx:field" tag. Now I think its issue in LC services in 3.0 which got fixed in 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I make a request for the Replies 
https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/replies?topicUuid=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877

I get

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">
    <opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">1</opensearch:totalResults>
    <opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">1</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <id>https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/replies?topicUuid=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877</id>
    <link href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/html/topic?id=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877" rel="alternate">
    </link>
    <link href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/replies?topicUuid=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877" rel="self">
    </link>
    <title type="text">testTopic1 Replies</title>
    <updated>2014-08-22T12:11:27.970Z</updated>
    <generator uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" version="4.5.0.0">IBM Connections - Discussion Forum</generator>
    <link href="http://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:81/communities/service/atom/community/instance?communityUuid=c5de2ed9-f856-4000-8e53-aa8dc57a23f5" rel="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/container" type="application/atom+xml">
    </link>
    <snx:communityUuid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">c5de2ed9-f856-4000-8e53-aa8dc57a23f5</snx:communityUuid>
    <entry xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">
    <id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095</id>
    <title type="text">Re: testTopic1</title>
    <category term="NotRecommendedByCurrentUser" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/flags">
    </category>
    <link xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/recommendation/entries?postUuid=47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095" rel="recommendations" type="application/atom+xml" snx:recommendation="0">
    </link>
    <published>2014-08-22T12:11:27.970Z</published>
    <author>
    <email>fadams@renovations.com</email>
    <name>Frank Adams</name>
    <snx:userid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">6B54D23A-0A70-C7A4-8525-7CA50082A393</snx:userid>
    <snx:userState xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">active</snx:userState>
    </author>
    <updated>2014-08-22T12:11:27.970Z</updated>
    <link href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/reply?replyUuid=47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml">
    </link>
    <link href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/reply?replyUuid=47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml">
    </link>
    <snx:field xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" name="CreateBlogComment.java" fid="66bc2e2e-5f7f-4303-9a05-c250b9c5b53a" type="file">
    <link name="CreateBlogComment.java" type="application/octet-stream" href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/download/CreateBlogComment.java?nodeId=66bc2e2e-5f7f-4303-9a05-c250b9c5b53a" length="4032">
    </link>
    <published>2014-08-22T12:11:28.375Z</published>
    <updated>2014-08-22T12:11:28.375Z</updated>
    </snx:field>
    <category term="forum-reply" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type">
    </category>
    <link href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/html/topic?id=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877#47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095" rel="alternate" type="text/html">
    </link>
    <link xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/replies?replyUuid=47595fe8-2bff-44f1-9340-9527ec015095" rel="replies" type="application/atom+xml" thr:count="0">
    </link>
    <thr:in-reply-to xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" ref="urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877" href="https://sdkdemo.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/forums/atom/topics?forumUuid=e6363aa5-38b7-4955-8a78-555db8151877" type="application/atom+xml">
    </thr:in-reply-to>
    <content type="html">
    &lt;p dir="ltr"&gt;
    &amp;nbsp;
    &lt;/p&gt;
    </content>
    <snx:permissions xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">none, create_forum, view_forum, edit_forum, del_forum, create_post, edit_personal_post, edit_all_post, del_personal_post, del_all_post, pin_topic, subscribe, lock_node, create_topictag, del_all_topictag, del_personal_topictag, create_forumtag, del_all_forumtag, del_personal_forumtag, view_category, edit_personal_question, edit_all_question, add_moderator</snx:permissions>
    </entry>
    </feed>
```

you should look for a snx:field like the following:

```
 <snx:field xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" name="CreateBlogComment.java" fid="66bc2e2e-5f7f-4303-9a05-c250b9c5b53a" type="file">
```

it's the element that describes the file / id and name.

*granted* this is Connections 4.5.  If you want a comment on 3.0, you'll have to post the XML response for calling the same API on your server